# Grab location less frequently with CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocationmanager

How could I use LocationManager to grab location less frequently?

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    print(locations)

    var truckLocation:CLLocation = locations[0]

    var latitude = truckLocation.coordinate.latitude
    var longitude = truckLocation.coordinate.longitude
    var latitude2 = 37.331469
    var longitude2 = -122.029825
    ref.childByAppendingPath("users/\(ref.authData.uid)/lat").setValue(latitude)
    ref.childByAppendingPath("users/\(ref.authData.uid)/lon").setValue(longitude)


    var latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    var lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

    var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    var location2: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude2, longitude2)
    var region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: false)

    var locA: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    var locB: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude2, longitude: longitude2)

}
```

In another part of my code, a button turns location monitoring on and off.  However, when active I'm currently pushing new location data to Firebase around once per second, which is way more than I need.  How can I make those updates much less frequent, say 5 minutes?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout:

Comment: @Joe Sloan, are you specifically after less frequent location updates, or would significant change location updates work for you?

Comment: @paulvs Significant change location updates would be really ideal!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges

Comment: Note that `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` might only work on real devices (not in the simulator) and even on real devices you might have to toggle on/off Airplane mode for it to trigger a significant location change.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm retrieving my location one time. If you read the documentation in Xcode it states that the manager.location returns the most recently retrieved user location.

```
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
      if let userLocation = manager.location {
         let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate 
         print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
      } else {
        print("we dont need user location for testing")
      }

    }
```